# how to change sammy routes

Tags: c#, routes, sammy.js

I use sammy scripts in spa template (c#, mvc 4).
Default links are the following: /#/home, /#/contacts, /#/faq, etc.
How can I change them on just /home, /contacts, /faq?

Answer (score 0):

The hash delineates the local part of the URL, which can be modified using the `location.hash` method. If you modify the entire URL, i.e. `location.href`, the browser will load the modified URL.

It looks like what you want to do is change your local URL, used by Sammy, to `#home` or `#contacts` so you don't have the empty hash in the beginning.

Below, Sammy is capturing changes to the URL, such as the user clicking on an anchor element with `href="#Home"` and then sending an AJAX request to get the template:

```
Sammy(function () {
/* Navigation requests
*/
    this.get("#:view", function () {
        switch (this.params.view) {                
            case "Home":
                $.ajax("Home/Index", {
                    type: "GET",
                    success: function (result) {
                        //Append result to page
                    },
                    cache: false
                });
                break;
            case "Search":
                $.ajax("Search/Index", {
                    type: "GET",
                    success: function (result) {
                        //Append result to page
                    },
                    cache: false
                });
                break;                
        };
    });
}).run();
```

Comment: Not exactly.
I have 2 routes: "#/home" and "#/contact". Everything works fine.
Now I want to change these 2 routes and to have the following: "home" and "contact" (without '#' prefix). When I do it a browser says "not found". How can I "cheat" a browser?

Comment: You can use `location.assign("home")` in place of the AJAX request, but that will load the new document, similar to how `location.href =` works. Since you said you're building a single-page app, I figured you would want to asynchronously load and input new content to the page, which means you'll have to work with local URLs which means hashes.